# Pass a value from a modal form to the original form and updating a label

Tags: asp.net

So I have a `ASP VB.NET` page that they have coded it with code behind from ten years ago.
Now in that page I have added a `label` and a `hyperlink`.  Clicking the hyperlink will open another form modal. They can directly edit and save stuff in that modal form. Now when I click the **"X"** button on this modal form and user sees the original first form, how can I update that `label` to something from one of the values that they saved in that other modal form?

Comment: Is this modal form an actual browser window, or something done with JavaScript? (i.e. jQuery)

Comment: Is everything it's doing done on postback, or is it using some Ajax?

Comment: @AnnL. : The modal is from a new page we created. It is ASP.NET MVC . It is an actual browser window. so I just called it with window.top.showmodal and I pass the URL of the new page to it

Comment: Are the MVC and Webforms (code-behind) apps on the same domain?

Comment: On the original first form, are you OK with refreshing the page and retrieving the values from a database (or wherever the values on the modal form were saved), or does the `label` update have to happen on the client side?

Comment: @AnnL. unfortunately has to be client side refresh .. currently other elements on that page are in an old school UpdatePanel of ASP.net so that's how they get updated Ajax style!

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code with the `window.top.showModal`? I'm having a little trouble visualizing it.